# Superscript my menu item title in my XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I want to have a part of my item's title as a superscript. Like the "²".

I want to do that in my drawermenu.xml (which only have `<menu>` and `<item>` markers), in the `android:title` attribute.

Here's my code :

```
<item android:title="The big title">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="The following is a superscript"
                android:id="@+id/id1"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon1"/>

            <item android:title="Another superscript string"
                android:id="@+id/id2"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon2"/>
        </menu>
</item>
```

I tried with :

```
android:title="The following is a <sup>superscript</sup>"
```

and with :

```
android:title="The following is a <sup><small>superscript</small></sup>"
```

With both, I have the following error :

```
Error:(9) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

In fact, at each time I've added a `<sup>` or `<small>` marker, it doesn't work.
Then I tried with that way :

```
android:title="The following is a &lt;sup&gt;superscript&lt;/sup&gt;"
```

I don't have any error with that, but it's really printed `The following is a <sup>superscript</sup>`.

How can I do that directly in my drawermenu.xml ?